# How to get random slice of python list of constant size. (smallest code)

Tags: python

Hi I have a List say 100 items, now i want a slice of say 6 items which should be randomly selected. Any way to do it in very simple simple concise statement???

This is what i came up with (but it will fetch in sequence)

```
 mylist #100 items
 N=100
 L=6
 start=random.randint(0,N-L);
 mylist[start:start+L]
```

Comment: what is wrong with your solution?

Comment: What would be the point of making it any more concise than that? This isn't C and "concise" doesn't map to "good" nor "faster" nor "more readable" much in C let alone Python. "Explicit is better than implicit." http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: `random.sample(mylist, size)` seems easy and good, I was now knowing :-)

Comment: @msw I agree to your point, I new to python so asked if there are some fancy way available that might be better and optimal solution.

Answer (score 13):

<strike>You could use the `shuffle()` method on the list before you slice.</strike>

If the order of the list matters, just make a copy of it first and slice out of the copy.

---

```
mylist #100 items
shuffleList = mylist
L=6
shuffle(shuffleList) 
start=random.randint(0,len(shuffleList)-L);
shuffleList[start:start+L]
```

As above, you could also use len() instead of defining the length of the list.

As THC4K suggested below, you could use the random.sample() method like below **IF** you want a set of random numbers from the list (which is how I read your question).

```
mylist #100 items
L=6
random.sample(mylist, L)
```

That's a lot tidier than my first try at it!

Comment: 1. This does something different. 2. there is random.population for what you do.

Comment: Something different to? The OPs code? The way I understood the question was that he/she wanted to select a group of random items from the list, not a slice from a random position in the list. But yes, random.sample looks good (that's what I found when looking for random.population in the docs).

Comment: whoops yeah I meant random.sample. The Ops code selects consecutive items, I assume that is intentional. But you're right, it could be either way ..

Comment: This is the bit that confused me a little "now i want a slice of say 6 items which should be randomly selected", I sort of assumed that meant 6 random items in the list, but yeah, could be either way I guess.

Comment: Yes, Thanks everyone for your answer random.sample(mylist, L) is what i wanted